# tv tuner on linux write “no signal”

Tags: dvb, linux-tv

Please, help
I have a TV tuner on Windows, there are no problems with it - all frequencies are found and shown, but in Linux it cannot find all frequencies (

https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Astrometa_DVB-T2
with Sony CXD2837ER

finds from 722000 frequencies to 778000, but from 786000 to 858000 writes - no signal
DVB-С

or tell me please where to write? I've never run into problems on Linux so I don't know where to write and where to create tickets.

i try write email to media-workshop@linuxtv.org, pkg-vdr-dvb-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org but there was no answer (

```
$ uname -a

Linux hs0 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



$ sudo w_scan -fc -S3 -Q1 -a /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend1

w_scan -fc -S3 -Q1 -a /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend1 

w_scan version 20170107 (compiled for DVB API 5.10)

WARNING: could not guess your country. Falling back to 'DE'

guessing country 'DE', use -c <country> to override

using settings for GERMANY

DVB cable

DVB-C

scan type CABLE, channellist 7

output format vdr-2.0

WARNING: could not guess your codepage. Falling back to 'UTF-8'

output charset 'UTF-8', use -C <charset> to override

-_-_-_-_ Getting frontend capabilities-_-_-_-_ 

Using DVB API 5.11

frontend 'Sony CXD2837ER DVB-T/T2/C demodulator' supports

INVERSION_AUTO

QAM_AUTO

FEC_AUTO

FREQ (42.00MHz ... 1002.00MHz)

SRATE (0.870MSym/s ... 11.700MSym/s)

-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ 

73000: sr6956 (time: 00:00.219) 

81000: sr6956 (time: 00:05.063) 
.
.
.
714000: sr6956 (time: 04:37.661) 

722000: sr6956 (time: 04:42.289)         signal ok: QAM_AUTO f = 722000 kHz S6956C999  (0:0:0)

        QAM_AUTO f = 722000 kHz S6956C999  (0:0:0) : updating network_id -> (0:100:0)

        already known: (QAM_AUTO f = 722000 kHz S6956C999  (0:100:0)), but not found by pids

        QAM_AUTO f = 722000 kHz S6956C999  (0:100:0) : updating tp ids -> (100:100:25)

        updating transponder:

           (QAM_AUTO f = 722000 kHz S6956C999  (100:100:25)) 0x0000

        to (QAM_256  f = 722000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:25)) 0x4044

        new transponder: (QAM_256  f = 730000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:26)) 0x4044

        new transponder: (QAM_256  f = 738000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:27)) 0x4044
.
.
.

        new transponder: (QAM_256  f = 850000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:46)) 0x4044

        new transponder: (QAM_256  f = 858000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:47)) 0x4044

730000: skipped (already known transponder)

738000: skipped (already known transponder)
.
.
.
810000: skipped (already known transponder)

818000: skipped (already known trans

Andry, [11.11.20 12:46]
ponder)

826000: skipped (already known transponder)

834000: skipped (already known transponder)

842000: skipped (already known transponder)

850000: skipped (already known transponder)

858000: skipped (already known transponder)

tune to: QAM_256  f = 722000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:25) (time: 04:46.489) 

 service = 001) info (H)

 service = 002) Perviy (H)
.
.
.
 service = 013) Spas (H)

tune to: QAM_256  f = 730000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:26) (time: 04:59.773) 

 service = 014) CTC (H)
.
.
 service = 023) Tv Mytishi (H)

tune to: QAM_256  f = 738000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:27) (time: 05:12.769) 

 service = 024) YOU (H)
.
.
 service = 036) Shopping live (H)

tune to: QAM_256  f = 746000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:29) (time: 05:25.769) 

 service = 037) Russkij illuzio (H)
.
.
 service = 048) 8 kanal (H)

tune to: QAM_256  f = 754000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:30) (time: 05:38.781) 

 service = 049) Indiyskoe kino (H)
.
.

 service = 060) Detsky (H)

tune to: QAM_256  f = 762000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:31) (time: 05:51.769) 

 service = 061) Ryzhiy (H)
.
.
 service = 072) Auto plus (H)

tune to: QAM_256  f = 770000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:33) (time: 06:04.781) 

 service = 073) Viasat Sport (H)
.
.
 service = 084) Dikiy (H)

tune to: QAM_256  f = 778000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:34) (time: 06:17.773) 

WARNING: received garbage data: crc = 0x04e7f1d2; expected crc = 0x9b1462c5

increasing filter timeout to 31 secs (pid:0 table_id:0 table_id_ext:-1).

 service = 085) CHE (H)
.
.
 service = 096) Doctor (H)

WARNING: received garbage data: crc = 0x776b71b8; expected crc = 0x643c495e

increasing filter timeout to 40 secs (pid:16 table_id:64 table_id_ext:-1).

tune t

Andry, [11.11.20 12:46]
o: QAM_256  f = 786000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:35) (time: 06:31.781) 

----------no signal----------

tune to: QAM_AUTO f = 786000 kHz S6956C999  (100:100:35) (time: 06:42.329)  (no signal)

----------no signal----------

tune to: QAM_256  f = 794000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:37) (time: 06:49.968) 

----------no signal----------

tune to: QAM_AUTO f = 794000 kHz S6956C999  (100:100:37) (time: 06:57.664)  (no signal)

----------no signal----------

tune to: QAM_256  f = 802000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:38) (time: 07:05.316) 

----------no signal----------
.
.
.
----------no signal----------

tune to: QAM_256  f = 850000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:46) (time: 08:37.192) 

----------no signal----------

tune to: QAM_AUTO f = 850000 kHz S6956C999  (100:100:46) (time: 08:44.840)  (no signal)

----------no signal----------

tune to: QAM_256  f = 858000 kHz S6956C0  (100:100:47) (time: 08:52.456) 

----------no signal----------

tune to: QAM_AUTO f = 858000 kHz S6956C999  (100:100:47) (time: 09:00.076)  (no signal)

----------no signal----------

(time: 09:07.744) dumping lists (96 services)

..

001) info;H:722000:M256:C:6956:663=27:664=rus@4:0:0:1:100:25:0

002) Perviy;H:722000:M256:C:6956:650=27:651=rus@3:652:0:2:100:25:0
.
.
.
096) Doctor;H:778000:M256:C:6956:572=2:573@3:0:0:96:100:34:0


Done, scan time: 09:07.744
```

Comment: Channel layouts differ from country to country. You did not supply the option `-c` to `w_scan` so it assumed Germany. Are you located in Germany?

Comment: @Hermann -c __ do not help write using settings for __________
Country identifier __ not defined. Using defaults.


and judging by the [code](https://github.com/tbsdtv/w_scan/blob/1ed568859da661ec8ac4212ecf98824563c76912/countries.c#L163), the country parameter only affects the preset of the search parameters that I already set - -fc -S3 -Q1

Comment: The list of frequencies is derived from the country. `-fc` selects DVB-C mode, `-S3` selects the symbol rate of 6956 ksyms, `-Q1` selects QAM64 (which, by the way, is rare in Germany, as seen at e.g. [this list of channels](https://helpdesk.vodafonekabelforum.de/sendb/belegung-22.html)). The frequencies are not given via command-line.